# TIdCompressorZLib doesn't work in FireMonkey app compiled for Android

Tags: android, delphi, indy, idhttp

I have a function using `TIdCompressorZLib` and `TIdHTTP`, like this:

```
pegar := tidhttp.create(nil);
compressor := TIdCompressorZLib.create(pegar);
seguro := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.create(pegar);
pegar.compressor := compressor;
pegar.Request.UserAgent := UserAgent;
pegar.Request.Accept := '*/*';
pegar.Request.AcceptEncoding := 'gzip, deflate';
pegar.Request.AcceptLanguage := 'pt-BR,pt;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7';
pegar.HTTPOptions := [hoForceEncodeParams];
pegar.ReadTimeout := 60000;
pegar.ConnectTimeout := 60000;
pegar.HandleRedirects := true;
pegar.IOHandler := seguro;
pegar.CookieManager := cookm;
pagina := pegar.Get(proxima_pagina);
```

This code works fine when compiled for Windows, but not for Android. On Android, `TIdCompressorZLib` does not unpack the source, returning unreadable characters.

Is there any way to fix this? I'm using Delphi 10.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the assignment of the `AcceptEncoding` property. Let `TIdHTTP` handle that internally for you based on the actual capabilities of the `Compressor`. You are explicitly granting permission to the HTTP server to send a compressed response even if the `Compressor` is not able to handle it (ie, if `Compressor.IsReady` is False).

That being said, Indy accesses ZLib on non-Windows platforms using dynamic load libraries. In this case, the `libz` dylib on 'Nix platforms (Android runs on top of Linux), which is likely not present in your Android project. `Compressor.IsReady` returns False if Indy can't load the ZLib library at runtime.  So, make sure that dylib is present in your deployment.  Indy has an `IdZLibSetLibPath()` function in the `IdZLibHeaders` unit if you need to specify the location of that file at runtime.